Blazor css doesn't honor height calc(100%);
This question is WHY DOES BLAZOR work differently.
NOT how to make an item 100% tall.
EDITUPDATE: The same css hand coded into an HTML file works as desired. The same css in Blazor doesn't.
I have a test HTML page that shows a div full height.
But when applied to blazor, the css doesn't work. I can't find any documentation that explains this behavior.
It looks like calc(100%) doesn't work in blazor.
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        body {
            color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
            background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
        }
        .container {
            height: calc(100%);
            background-color: red;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">container
        </div>
    </body>
</html>


Hand Coded HTML


MainLayout.razor
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="container">container
</div>

app.css
body {
    color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

.container {
    height: calc(100%);
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

Blazor app


Why height: calc( 100% )? Why not just height: 100%;?

Using a % value with height: won't do anything unless the element's layout parent (body in this case) has a defined height - your CSS does not cause body to have a defined height, so 100% of nothing is... nothing.

html, body, .container {height: 100%};

@BrettDonald 100vh is the preferred option today.

@Dai, height:100% also doesn't work.
The hand coded css works. The same css in blazor, doesn't.

@Displayname Show us the DOM tree when you use Blazor.

Not sure what does Blazor do for its build-in framework. To achieve you requirement, you can  explicitly set the height of the html and body elements to 100%/100vh in your CSS to ensure that the container div can take the full height.
html,body {
    height: 100vh;
    color: rgb(170, 170, 170);
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

.container {
    height: calc(100%);
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

If you also need the width to be full width, you need add max-width:100%;:
.container {
    max-width:100%;
    height: calc(100%);
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


I don't think you do need to set body or html, though.  If you set height of a div to 100vh, that should override html or body boxes, unless they are also set to clip with overflow:hidden or something.

Blazor does not generate any <div> s that you didn't write yourself.
